# Pick up a directory by JFilechooser and save Itext Report in .pdf to that directory in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

[image]

I created this forms for backup function by Netbeans.

When I select date from the Jdaychooser(date validation included in my code)and click OK button,  JFilechooser open for asking saving directory.(shown in screenshot below).

I want below functionality to be done ;

**When click OK,Itext generated report must save into selected directory from JFilchooser..**

I coded but not 100% working (It's only saving pdf in my project included directory )

help me for correct my code...

method for OK button action performed ;

```
private void backupOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int result;

    Date nowdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());  
    Date backday  =  backup_date.getDate();


    if(backday==null){//checking the date is null or not
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter the Date ...");

    }else if(!backday.before(nowdate)){//checking given date before todays date or not
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Date before Todays date...");

    }else{
        // backup function goes here
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
//            chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            chooser.setDialogTitle("Save Backup");
            chooser.setApproveButtonText("Save");
            //disables the all filesoptioning here
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY); 
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

            if(chooser.showOpenDialog(this)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
//                System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "+ chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
//                System.out.print("getSelectedFile() : "+chooser.getSelectedFile());


            // creating the pdf for supplier details


            try {
                Document pdfsup = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfsup, new FileOutputStream("Supplier Details Report.pdf"));

                pdfsup.open();
            Image imgsup = Image.getInstance("hedder.png");
           // pdfsup.add(new Paragraph("Suppliers"));
            pdfsup.add(imgsup);
            pdfsup.add(new Paragraph("Supplier Details Report",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE)));
            pdfsup.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
            pdfsup.add(new Paragraph("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));

            PdfPTable tablesup= new PdfPTable(2);

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Title"));
            cell.setColspan(4);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.PINK);
            tablesup.addCell(cell);

            tablesup.addCell("Supplier ID");
            tablesup.addCell("Supplier ID2");
            tablesup.addCell("Supplier ID3");
            tablesup.addCell("Supplier ID4");
            pdfsup.add(tablesup);

            pdfsup.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Report Saved...");


            } catch (DocumentException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("No Selection");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You use the fixed file name `"Supplier Details Report.pdf"` in the current working directory, not the directory and file returned by the `chooser`. Adapt your `PdfWriter.getInstance` accordingly

Comment: I get the idea .. But how to do that @mkl Tried but not successful..

Comment: `PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfsup, new FileOutputStream(new File(chooser.getSelectedFile(), "Supplier Details Report.pdf")));`, assuming that you've only allowed for directory selection

Comment: @MadProgrammer It works.. Thanks very much :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please make that an actual answer, not a mere comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new FileOutputStream("Supplier Details Report.pdf")` will simple create a reference to a file in the current working directory, it has no path information associated with, you've basically ignored anything the `JFileChooser` had provided.

Consider using something more like...

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfsup, new FileOutputStream(new File(chooser.getSelectedFile(), "Supplier Details Report.pdf")));
```

Which uses the `selectedFile` from the `JFileChooser`, assuming that you've only allowed for directory selection